# Elementary Geometry from an Advanced Standpoint - Theorem B-5

Tags: geometry

I'm studying Geometry through the book "Elementary Geometry from an Advanced Standpoint" by Edwin E. Moise. In page 63 he states:

"THEOREM B-5. IF A-B-C, then A, B, and C are three different points of
the same line.
This held, of course, under our original definition of the relation A-B-C.
For convenience of reference, we list the basic properties of betweenness.

B-1. If A-B-C, then C-B-A.

B-2. Of any three points on a line, exactly one is between the other two.

B-3. Any four points of a line can be named in an order A, B, C, D, in such a
way that A-B-C-D.

B-4. If A and B are any two points, then (1) there is a point C such that A-B-C,
and (2) there is a point D such that A-D-B.

B-5. If A-B-C, then A, B, and C are three different points of the same line."

Theorems B-1 through B-4 were proven previosly in the former pages but, as one can see, he provides no proof whatsoeve for B-5, which he states as a Theorem.

How can one prove this? Is this provable based on the previously given postulates, definitions and theorems? Because my impression is that what he stated as Theorem B-5 should have been, in fact, part of the definition of betweeness.

Appreciate any comments or help or, if anyone can prove this, the step-by-step.

Cheers

ps.

Moise uses this definition for betweenness:

DEFINITION. Let A, B, and C be three collinear points. If
AB + BC = AC,
then B is between A and C. In this case we write A-B-C.

But as one can see, suppose A = B = C, so AB = 0, BC = 0 and AC = 0.

In this case, AB + BC = AC (0 + 0 = 0).

Even if A = B ≠ C the definition would hold.

Comment: It *does* seem to be part of the definition of between-ness, as you have writen it. According to the definition that you have written, a *precondition* of the relation $A$-$B$-$C$ is that $A$, $B$, $C$ are three collinear points.